# Log4j logging problem with 2 ears in Weblogic

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm deploying 2 ears in Weblogic 10, A and B. In both of them I have a "log4j.properties" file. At the startup, when the first ear is loading, the logs are to the right file "A.log", but when the second ear is loading, all logs are going to the "B.log" file, even logs related to the first ear.
I missed something... any idea ?

Thanks

**Edit/Solution :**
Classloader issue. 
Add to the weblogic-application.xml :

`<wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name> 
  </wls:prefer-application-packages>`

Thks to everyone :)

Comment: What is the path of your log4j.properties within the EAR? and also, are you using the log4j which is built into Wlogic 10 or your own separately?

Comment: You might want to refer to the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576937/using-log4j-logging-in-weblogic-9-10

Comment: JoseK : my log4j.properties is in a root "conf" folder. Each ear has a "log4j-1.2.15.jar" in the APP-INF\lib

Comment: l'éponge est un con: can you try the 2 steps from here - put the individual files at /APP-INF/classes/log4j.properties file and use the tag wls:prefer-application-packages. http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/2010/04/22/dynamically-changing-log-level-with-weblogic-log4j-jmx-and-wlst/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be my guess that the log4j library that is used by the Weblogic server is used in both your web applications.

If this is the case, both web apps would share a root classloader serving the global libraries loade by Weblogic.

If your web apps each provide a copy of log4j, and if you can choose to load the application classes before the server classes (I don't know Weblogic but for WebSphere the setting is 'classloader mode: parent first / parent last') that might solve your problem.

Comment: wls:prefer-application-packages is what you're looking for.

Comment: Excellent!! I am searching for this for 5 days now :)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it's hard to tell from here but you can try these:

1) check if the logger names in both of your log4j property files are unique.
2) I think that the .properties file are not cached on disk but still deleting the application
   deployment directories (should be separate for both the EAR's )

Comment: Logger names are unique. Cache is cleaned at every startup with a .bat